# Is there a way to inject a scoped service into a custom Controller Activator (or Page Model Activator Provider)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I am working on an ASP.NET Core app and am using a custom [`PageModelActivatorProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/IPageModelActivatorProvider.cs) to create my razor pages. This app has user's and implements [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) using [`AddIdentityCore`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L33). I have added a `SignInManager` and authentication as well:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
.AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
    };
});
```

I have created a custom `UserStore` and added it as a scoped service within my `Program.cs` file:

```
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString");

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPageModelActivatorProvider, WebUIPageModelActivatorProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository>(_ => new UserRepository(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore>();
```

The `UserManager` and `SignInManager` classes are added as scoped services within `AddIdentityCore` and [`AddSignInManager`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityBuilderExtensions.cs#L58) methods, respectively.

My `PageModelActivatorProvider` class creates a `LoginModel` page model, which takes a `UserManager` and a `SignInManager`. Both of these are scoped services, however my `PageModelActivatorProvider` is registered as a singleton service, so I cannot inject the `UserManager` and `SignInManager` via constructor injection. When I try using the `IServiceProvider` to `GetRequiredService`, I get the following exception:

```
'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[DataAccess.ApplicationUser]' from root provider.'
```

I get the same exception for `UserManager` and `SignInManager` because they are all registered as scoped services and I am trying to access them within a singleton service.

```
public sealed class WebUIPageModelActivatorProvider : IPageModelActivatorProvider, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    
    public WebUIPageModelActivatorProvider(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        // Create Singleton components
        _services = services;
    }

    public Func<PageContext, object> CreateActivator(CompiledPageActionDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return (context) => _CreatePageModelType(context, descriptor.ModelTypeInfo!.AsType());
    }

    public Action<PageContext, object>? CreateReleaser(CompiledPageActionDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return (context, pageModel) => (pageModel as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }

    private object _CreatePageModelType(PageContext context, Type pageModelType)
    {
        // Scoped components for Identity Core
        IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = _services.GetRequiredService<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = _services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()!;
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager = _services.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()!;

        // Create Transient components
        switch (pageModelType.Name)
        {
            case nameof(IndexModel):
                return new IndexModel();

            case nameof(LoginModel):
                return new LoginModel(userManager, signInManager, Logger<LoginModel>());

            default: throw new NotImplementedException(pageModelType.FullName);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Release singleton components here, if needed
    }

    private ILogger<T> Logger<T>() => this._loggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();
```

Next I tried creating an `IServiceScope` to resolve my scoped services:

```
...
private object _CreatePageModelType(PageContext context, Type pageModelType)
    {
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            // Scoped components for Identity Core
            IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()!;
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()!;

            // Create Transient components
            switch (pageModelType.Name)
            {
                case nameof(IndexModel):
                    return new IndexModel();

                case nameof(LoginModel):
                    return new LoginModel(userManager, signInManager, Logger<LoginModel>());

                default: throw new NotImplementedException(pageModelType.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
...
```

This method successfully created the scoped services and injected them into my `LoginModel`, however, after they were injected, they were disposed of and I received the following exception:

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'UserManager`1'.
```

**Is there a way to inject a scoped service into a custom `PageModelActivatorProvider`?**

Comment: Try injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`, and use `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices` to get the `IServiceProvider` for the current request, which you can use to resolve your scoped services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into the singleton service, and use `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices` to get the `IServiceProvider` for the current request which you can use to resolve your scoped services.

```cs
public sealed class WebUIPageModelActivatorProvider : IPageModelActivatorProvider, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public WebUIPageModelActivatorProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    private object _CreatePageModelType(PageContext context, Type pageModelType)
    {
        IServiceProvider services = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        
        // Scoped components for Identity Core
        IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = services.GetRequiredService<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()!;
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager = services.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()!;

        ...
```